# How to Update FormView?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, visual-studio, formview

I have FormView:

```
 <asp:FormView ID="fvReport" runat="server" AllowPaging="false" 
        OnModeChanging="fvReport_ModeChanging"  
        OnItemUpdating="fvReport_ItemUpdating" 
        DataKeyNames="id" DataSourceID="ObjectReport">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lbEdit" runat="server" CausesValidation="true" CommandName="Edit" >Edit</asp:LinkButton>
        <table>
           <tr id="order">
               <td style="Width:90px;">order:</td>
               <td><asp:textbox ID="Textbox7" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("order") %>' Width="600px" TextMode="MultiLine" ReadOnly="True" Rows="3" BorderStyle="NotSet" CssClass="text-details"></asp:textbox></td></tr>
           <tr id="purpose">
               <td style="Width:90px;">purpose:</td>
               <td><asp:textbox ID="Textbox8" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("purpose") %>' Height="34px" Width="600px" TextMode="MultiLine" ReadOnly="True" CssClass="text-details"></asp:textbox></td></tr>
           <tr id="feature_runs">
               <td style="Width:90px;">features:</td>
               <td><asp:textbox ID="Textbox9" runat="server" Text='<%# Convert.ToString(Eval("features")).Replace( "Esc", "Еsс")%>' Height="52px" Width="600px"  ReadOnly="True" TextMode="MultiLine" Font-Italic="True" ForeColor="Red" Enabled="false" CssClass="text-details"></asp:textbox></td></tr>
           <tr id="settings">
               <td style="Width:90px;">settings:</td>
               <td><asp:textbox ID="Textbox10" runat="server" Text='<%# Convert.ToString(Eval("settings")).Replace( "Esc", "Еsс") %>' Height="44px" Width="600px"  TextMode="MultiLine" ReadOnly="True" CssClass="text-details"></asp:textbox></td></tr>
        </table>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <table>
           <tr id="order">
               <td style="Width:90px;">order:</td>
               <td><asp:textbox ID="Textbox7" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("order") %>' Width="600px" TextMode="MultiLine" ReadOnly="True" Rows="3" BorderStyle="NotSet" CssClass="text-details"></asp:textbox></td></tr>
           <tr id="purpose">
               <td style="Width:90px;">purpose:</td>
               <td><asp:textbox ID="Textbox8" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("purpose") %>' Height="34px" Width="600px" TextMode="MultiLine" ReadOnly="True" CssClass="text-details"></asp:textbox></td></tr>
           <tr id="feature_runs">
               <td style="Width:90px;">features:</td>
               <td><asp:textbox ID="Textbox9" runat="server" Text='<%# Convert.ToString(Eval("features")).Replace( "Esc", "Еsс")%>' Height="52px" Width="600px"  ReadOnly="True" TextMode="MultiLine" Font-Italic="True" ForeColor="Red" Enabled="false" CssClass="text-details"></asp:textbox></td></tr>
           <tr id="settings">
               <td style="Width:90px;">settings:</td>
               <td><asp:textbox ID="Textbox10" runat="server" Text='<%# Convert.ToString(Eval("settings")).Replace( "Esc", "Еsс") %>' Height="44px" Width="600px"  TextMode="MultiLine" ReadOnly="True" CssClass="text-details"></asp:textbox></td></tr>
        </table>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lbUpdate" runat="server" CausesValidation="true" CommandName="Update" >Save</asp:LinkButton>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lbCancel" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="Cancel">Cancel</asp:LinkButton>
    </EditItemTemplate>
    </asp:FormView>
```

ObjectDataSource :

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectReport" runat="server"
       TypeName = "ObjectDataSources.CS.ConnectionToDB"
       SelectMethod = "GetReportById" UpdateMethod="">
   <SelectParameters>
       <asp:Parameter Name="report_id" Type ="Int32" />
   </SelectParameters>
   <UpdateParameters>
       <asp:Parameter Name="report_id" Type ="Int32" />
       <asp:Parameter Name="settings" Type = "String" />
       <asp:Parameter Name="purpose" Type = "String" />
       <asp:Parameter Name="order" Type = "String" />
       <asp:Parameter Name="features" Type = "String" />
   </UpdateParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

UpdateMetod:

```
    public int UpdateReportById(int report_id, string settings, string purpose, string order, string features)
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_connectionString);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Update main_report SET settings = @settings, " + 
                "purpose = @purpose, order = @order, " +
                "features = @features WHERE id = @id", conn);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = report_id;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@settings", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = settings;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@purpose", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = purpose;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@order", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = order;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@features", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = features;
            int result = 0;
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (SqlException e)
            {
                throw new Exception("UpdateReportById Exception.");
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
            return result;
        }
```

fvReport_ItemUpdating:

```
protected void fvReport_ItemUpdating(Object sender, FormViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    switch (fvReport.CurrentMode)
    {
        case FormViewMode.Edit:
            fvReport.AllowPaging = false;
            lbl.Text = "Update!!!";
            fvReport.ChangeMode(FormViewMode.ReadOnly);
            fvReport.DataBind();
            break;
    }
    fvReport.DataBind();
}
```

but the data is not updated (label is updated :) ). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: it turned out, that I forgot to set UpdateMetod for the Formview. 
But when I try to update I receive following exception: "The parameterized query '(@report_id int,@settings,@purpose varchar(8000),@order varchar(8000),@features' expects the parameter '@settings', which was not supplied."

Comment: can you post your complete formview code. so that It will be easy to figure out the solution.

Comment: and if my new edit didn't work please also post the code of your 'UpdateMetod'

Comment: @Muhammad Akhtar & @lKashef: I posted

Comment: Edited answer and read carefully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put `updatedEvent` in your code instead of `updatingEvent`

```
switch (fvReport.CurrentMode)
{
    case FormViewMode.Edit:
        fvReport.AllowPaging = false;
        lbl.Text = "Update!!!";
        fvReport.ChangeMode(FormViewMode.ReadOnly);
        fvReport.DataBind();
        break;
}
fvReport.DataBind();
```

**Edit:** After you posted your complete form design I have noticed that in your edit profile you have bound your value like...

```
Text='<%# Eval("order") %>'
```

But this function provides only one way binding. It means it will populate the value from your DB to control.

However this will not pass the values back when you are trying to update your values.

You have to use `Bind instead Eval`, that provide two way binding. like..

```
Text='<%# Bind("order") %>'
```

Add in all your controls in the Edit and Insert template.

Comment: yah, this was another issue, but you have do things mentioned in my answer.

Comment: ok, thanks. Can you help me with exception, that I posted in comment for my question?

Comment: @Muhammad Akhtar .. I dunno if this has anything to do with the problem source but Great point! +1

Comment: @Muhammad Akhtar: I changed Eval to Bind in EditItemTemplate, but FormView is not uptated yet(

Comment: so what's the issue now? post what error you are getting now ?

Comment: I am not getting issue now, but after clicking button "Update" data are not updated and I receive previous data after postback.

Comment: @Muhammad Akhtar: Excuse me, I did check for empty data in fvReport_ItemUpdating so I can't see issue.  This issue is: "ObjectDataSource 'ObjectReport' could not find a non-generic method 'UpdateReportById' that has parameters: settings, purpose, order, features, branch_desc, cons_details, system, report_group, report_type, report_status' So if you see in datatable I have more columns then I use in update.

Comment: Can you check from DB, whether its updated or not ? make breakpoint on UpdateReportById method and check values of parameters. I guess the problem Id is not passed to your method.

Comment: @Muhammad Akhtar: Do I need to add fields to UpdateMetod, which only extracts in SelectMetod, but do not need to change?

Comment: check your update method name that you provide to your datasource.

Comment: thaks a lot for help!!! You were right - the problem Id was not passed to my Update method.

Comment: @Muhammad Akhtar. Yes, this solution works. Excuse me, but I haven't access to log in from this computer, I entered only name and e-mail. I voted from another account with the same login - "DmitrB". Are there any differences from what account to vote?

Comment: I would suggest you to use only one account. By the way, why you are using two account ?

Comment: @Muhammad Akhtar. I didn't know, that I could log in using openId. I did it earlier using gmail account, but now blocked access to such resources, so I use temporary account to ask questions (I entered only login and e-mail ). And today I learned, that I can log in using openId)

Comment: @Muhammad Akhtar: Now I will always use another account with openid (dmitryb) - DmitryB (26 : 5)

Comment: that will be better for you, if you use your one profile and that will be rich time by time.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the `DataSourceControlID` property of your `FormView`

```
    <asp:FormView ID="fvReport" runat="server" AllowPaging="false" 
                OnModeChanging="fvReport_ModeChanging"  
                OnItemUpdating="fvReport_ItemUpdating" 
                DataKeyNames="id" 
                DataSourceID="ObjectReport">
```

Comment: thanks, but I did it in code-behind. Here I forgot to set UpdateMetod. 
But when I try to update I receive following exception:
"The parameterized query '(@report_id int,@settings,@purpose varchar(8000),@order varchar(8000),@features' expects the parameter '@settings', which was not supplied."

Comment: hmmm..Did you add the parameter "@settings" to your command parameters in your data access code ?

Comment: yes, I did. `public int UpdateReportById(int report_id, string settings, string purpose, string order, string features)`
and parameter is `cmd.Parameters.Add("@settings", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = settings`;

Comment: 1. Could you specify the datatype, constraints, name, and all the information about the column settings in your database and be careful and respect the 'case sensitive'.
2. post the complete code to your "UpdateReportById" method.